# I'm creating a social web using django, I need to create a group model with an group admin who can perform activities such as add and remove members

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'd like that when a group is created then the instance of the profile that creates the group automatically becomes the group admin likewise he/she becomes a group member,couple of basic methods tried returns manytomany relationship errors pointing at add,set functions, how can this be achieved??, I'm using django restframework.

Groups model and serializer.

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(
        help_text='Describe this group...', max_length=350, blank=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        "profiles.Profile", blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='group_admin')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        "profiles.Profile", blank=True, related_name='members')
    posts = models.ForeignKey(
        "posts.Post", blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='group_posts')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "profiles.Profile", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='group_creator')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['id', 'group_name', 'members',
                  'posts', 'created_by', 'created']
        depth = 1
```

Views

```py
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serialiazer_class = GroupSerializer
    queryset=Group.objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: I have added the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your serializer's `create` method and do your post-process there like this:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        request = self.context['request']

        instance.admin = request.user.profile
        instance.save()
        instance.members.add(request.user.profile)
```

`ModelViewSet` adds `request` to the serializer context, so you have access to `request.user` which you can then set as the admin (assuming `profile` has a `OneToOneField` relation with `user`).

Comment: Thank you so much! though i have realised that this code restricts a single user to be only a group admin in a single group. On creating another group with the same user as an admin then it throws this error : UNIQUE constraint failed: groups_group.admin_id

Comment: Thats because you defined admin as a one to one field. This will ensure the field can only be unique

Comment: Edited the field to manytomany and now i'm having this error: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use admin.set() instead. After that I have refactored the admin to be populated like you've done for the members many to many field and voila! i works like a charm.

Comment: Sounds good! Do [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1027465) this answer if it helped you at all.

Comment: Hey Brian, Check my new question please

Answer (score 0):

Edited the group admin field in the model to a manytomany, then tweaked an answer here to.

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = super().create(validated_data)
    request = self.context['request']

    instance.admin.add(request.user.profile)
    instance.save()
    instance.members.add(request.user.profile)
```